# Trying to find the kernel regression fit using kreg()

Tags: r, regression

I have simple data: y and multiple x's which I'm testing individually, and I need the kernel regression fit for each.

```
library(gplm)
data = read.csv("https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/datasets/ozone.data",header=T,sep='\t')
y=data$ozone
x1=data$radiation
x2=data$temperature
x3=data$wind
kreg(x1,y)
kreg(x2,y)
kreg(x3,y)
```

But I don't understand what the output means. Is bandwidth the only parameter needed for kernel regression? How do I get the model fit? Thanks in advance!